# Change the stage background color in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I am trying to change the stage background color, instead of the default white. 
The following image shows a simple stage with a scene containing nodes/panes.

[image]

I made my own simple top utility version, viewed as a node within the stage, but that created more difficulty when it came to resizing, dragging the window and so on, so **looking after a solution that will let me edit & style the default stage itself, by referring directly to the stage.**

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your current styling code? Something that others can run and try.

Comment: Which styling code? - For the custom made bar?

Comment: That look is chosen by the OS. Depending on the os it may or may not be possible to make that choice on a per-window basis, but certainly it requires system dependent logic. Not sure if some Java exists allowing you to do that for the most common OS types, but one way or another you're most likely better of going through the trouble of implementing the resizing yourself...

Comment: Right, was afraid of that. Thanks for the feedback. :-) More work it is!

Answer (score -2):

To get a complete control over the stage, obviously you have to implement your own behavior using StageStyle.TRANSPARENT.

Below is a quick demo of a transparent stage, hooking the resizing logic and setting the drag to the header. I hope this can help you to get some ideas of how to go with your requirement.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class ResizableCustomStage_Demo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {


        Button button1 = new Button("Open Decorated");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> {
            StackPane node = new StackPane(new Label("DECORATED"));
            node.setPadding(new Insets(15));
            node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#999999;-fx-font-size:16px;");

            StackPane body = new StackPane(new Group(node));
            Stage stg = new Stage();
            stg.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            stg.setScene(new Scene(body, 300, 300, Color.TRANSPARENT));
            stg.show();
        });


        Button button2 = new Button("Open Custom");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> {
            StackPane node = new StackPane(new Label("CUSTOM"));
            node.setPadding(new Insets(15));
            node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;-fx-font-size:16px;");

            StackPane body = new StackPane(new Group(node));
            VBox.setVgrow(body, Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox root = new VBox(buildDraggableHeader(), body);
            root.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:red;-fx-background-color:pink;");

            Stage stg = new Stage();
            stg.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stg.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.PINK));
            // EXPLICITLY INCLUDING THE RESIZE LOGIC !!!
            stg.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new ResizeHandler(stg));
            stg.show();
        });

        Button button3 = new Button("Open Transparent");
        button3.setOnAction(e -> {
            StackPane node = new StackPane(new Label("TRANSPARENT"));
            node.setPadding(new Insets(15));
            node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;-fx-font-size:16px;");

            StackPane body = new StackPane(new Group(node));
            VBox.setVgrow(body, Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox root = new VBox(buildDraggableHeader(), body);
            root.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:green;-fx-background-color:transparent;");

            Stage stg = new Stage();
            stg.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            stg.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.TRANSPARENT));
            // EXPLICITLY INCLUDING THE RESIZE LOGIC !!!
            stg.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new ResizeHandler(stg));
            stg.show();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(button1, button2, button3);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.setTitle("Stage Styles Demo");
        stage.show();
    }

    private Node buildDraggableHeader() {
        BorderPane header = new BorderPane();
        header.setMinHeight(24);
        header.setRight(new HBox(new Button("-"), new Button("0"), new Button("X")));
        StackPane title = new StackPane(new Label("Draggable Header"));
        title.setStyle("-fx-font-weight:bold;");
        title.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        header.setLeft(title);
        header.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#999999;-fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;-fx-border-color:#555555;");
        header.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 3));

        // EXPLICITLY INCLUDING THE DRAG LOGIC !!!
        DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty y = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        header.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            x.set(e.getSceneX());
            y.set(e.getSceneY());
        });
        header.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            header.getScene().getWindow().setX(e.getScreenX() - x.get());
            header.getScene().getWindow().setY(e.getScreenY() - y.get());
        });

        return header;
    }

    /**
     * Handler to process the resizing of the the given stage.
     */
    class ResizeHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        /**
         * Space to consider around the stage border for resizing
         */
        private static final double BORDER = 6;

        /**
         * Space to consider the border width factor while resizing
         */
        private static final double BORDER_WIDTH_FACTOR = 6;

        private final Window window;
        /**
         * Current cursor reference to the scene
         */
        private Cursor cursor = Cursor.DEFAULT;

        /**
         * X position of the drag start
         */
        private double startX = 0;

        /**
         * Y position of the drag start
         */
        private double startY = 0;

        ResizeHandler(final Window window) {
            this.window = window;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
            final EventType<? extends MouseEvent> eventType = event.getEventType();
            final Scene scene = window.getScene();
            final double mouseEventX = event.getSceneX();
            final double mouseEventY = event.getSceneY();
            final double sceneWidth = scene.getWidth();
            final double sceneHeight = scene.getHeight();
            final boolean isResizable = true;

            if (isResizable) {
                if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED.equals(eventType)) {
                    assignCursor(scene, event, mouseEventX, mouseEventY, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

                } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED.equals(eventType)) {
                    startX = window.getWidth() - mouseEventX;
                    startY = window.getHeight() - mouseEventY;
                    consumeEventIfNotDefaultCursor(event);

                } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED.equals(eventType) && !Cursor.DEFAULT.equals(cursor)) {
                    consumeEventIfNotDefaultCursor(event);
                    if (!Cursor.W_RESIZE.equals(cursor) && !Cursor.E_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                        handleHeightResize(event);
                    }

                    if (!Cursor.N_RESIZE.equals(cursor) && !Cursor.S_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                        handleWidthResize(event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void assignCursor(final Scene scene, final MouseEvent event, final double mouseEventX,
                                  final double mouseEventY, final double sceneWidth, final double sceneHeight) {
            final Cursor cursor1;

            if (mouseEventX < BORDER && mouseEventY < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.NW_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX < BORDER && mouseEventY > sceneHeight - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.SW_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - BORDER
                    && mouseEventY < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.NE_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - BORDER && mouseEventY > sceneHeight - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.SE_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.W_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.E_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventY < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.N_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventY > sceneHeight - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.S_RESIZE;
            } else {
                cursor1 = Cursor.DEFAULT;
            }
            cursor = cursor1;
            scene.setCursor(cursor);
        }

        /**
         * Consumes the mouse event if the cursor is not the DEFAULT cursor.
         *
         * @param event MouseEvent instance
         */
        private void consumeEventIfNotDefaultCursor(final MouseEvent event) {
            if (!cursor.equals(Cursor.DEFAULT)) {
                event.consume();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Processes the vertical drag movement and resizes the window height.
         *
         * @param event MouseEvent instance
         */
        private void handleHeightResize(final MouseEvent event) {
            final double mouseEventY = event.getSceneY();
            final double minHeight = 30;
            if (Cursor.NW_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                    || Cursor.N_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                    || Cursor.NE_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                if (window.getHeight() > minHeight || mouseEventY < 0) {
                    final double newHeight = window.getY() - event.getScreenY() + window.getHeight();
                    window.setHeight(max(newHeight, minHeight));
                    window.setY(event.getScreenY());
                }
            } else if (window.getHeight() > minHeight || mouseEventY + startY - window.getHeight() > 0) {
                final double newHeight = mouseEventY + startY;
                window.setHeight(max(newHeight, minHeight));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Processes the horizontal drag movement and resizes the window width.
         *
         * @param event MouseEvent instance
         */
        private void handleWidthResize(final MouseEvent event) {
            final double mouseEventX = event.getSceneX();
            final double minWidth = 100;
            if (Cursor.NW_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                    || Cursor.W_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                    || Cursor.SW_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                if (window.getWidth() > minWidth || mouseEventX < 0) {
                    final double newWidth = window.getX() - event.getScreenX() + window.getWidth();
                    window.setWidth(max(newWidth, minWidth));
                    window.setX(event.getScreenX());
                }
            } else if (window.getWidth() > minWidth || mouseEventX + startX - window.getWidth() > 0) {
                final double newWidth = mouseEventX + startX;
                window.setWidth(max(newWidth, minWidth));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Determines the max value among the provided two values.
         *
         * @param value1 First value
         * @param value2 Second value
         * @return Maximum value of the given two values.
         */
        private double max(final double value1, final double value2) {
            return value1 > value2 ? value1 : value2;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String... a) {
        Application.launch(a);
    }
}
```